# CXFRS and CXF endpoints conflict in the same application

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

I have an app where in the Camel context I have defined a CXFRS endpoint for a publishing REST API. A snippet from the Camel route:

```
    from("cxfrs:http://localhost:18080?resourceClasses=com.example.RestService&bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&providers=#jsonProvider")
            .toD("direct:${header.operationName}");
```

I also need to publish a separate SOAP service (but hosted in the same app). The bean definition for the CXF endpoint is:

```
  <!-- setting up a Camel CXF web-service -->
  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="orderEndpoint"
                   address="http://localhost:9000/order/"
                   serviceClass="camelinaction.order.OrderEndpoint"
                   wsdlURL="wsdl/order.wsdl">
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

When loading the app with both, the SOAP service will work but the REST service will not. The connection is being refused at port 18080. This is solved by removing the endpoint for the SOAP service. I suspect that by wiring both endpoints, the SOAP endpoint is overriding defaults the REST endpoint needs. Is there anything that needs to be manually configured to use CXF and CXFRS in the same context?